# How to open my Android app on a long press of home, back or recent apps button?

Tags: java, android

I want my users to be able to launch my app by long pressing back button, recent apps button or home button. Or even long press on volume up/down or power button.... something which would allow users to execute my app without touching a screen icon.

I offer similar voice solution to Google Now, which btw. opens after a long press on home button. Any way I can do the same? I get this question from my users almost daily...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your users will be able to do this without rooting. I found this thread which is worth reading:

http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/183113-button-remapping.html

alternatively they mentioned [Go Launcher app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

I've read through the list of [`ACTION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#constants)s that you can use for starting an activity through intents, but can not find any of the ones you wanted. If you do find any other ACTION useful there is more info on how to actually do it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).