# How to add my app to long press on home button?

Tags: android, long-press, android-homebutton

This is what happens when I **long press** on the **home button** on my Android device.
As you can see, except Google Now, there are two other apps...

I need to add my own App to this menu, yet I am unable to find anywhere how to go about coding it.

Answers I've found on StackOverflow, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238003/how-to-open-my-android-app-on-a-long-press-of-home-back-or-recent-apps-button) are saying, that it's not possible, I have to be rooted, etc. However, my phone is not rooted and these two other apps were able to do it. How?

I'll pay in beer and gold :)

[image: Screenshot]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My app wouldn't appear in the recent apps list either until I added a label to the main activity.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name_short" > <!-- this attribute can't be empty -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```